# Is there a way for a desktop app (Electron)to access and read files in a given folder on local file system (vs requiring user to upload folder)

Tags: web, browser, electron, filesystems, html5-filesystem

I would like our web-application to read images from our user's selected folder. The current UX is that the user must upload the folder of images, which takes an unacceptable amount of time, so we'd like to not require uploads. We're currently using the FileSystem API.

My hunch is that this is not doable with a web-app. If that's true, my next question is... can it be doable if it was a progressive web-app? What about an electron/desktop app?

EDIT:
Sorry I should have specified.... Given a folder of images, I would like to 1) prompt the user to accept permission for the app to read those images *once* and then 2) allow the app to read images from that folder forever, regardless of whether they log out or reopen the app. Will edit original post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) should be able to do what you want - perhaps you're not doing it right

Comment: Sorry I should have specified.... Given a folder of images, I would like to 1) prompt the user to accept permission for the app to read those images _once_ and then 2) allow the app to read images from that folder forever, regardless of whether they log out or reopen the app. Will edit original post.

Comment: _"2) allow the app to read images from that folder forever, regardless of whether they log out or reopen the app."_ It appears it is not possible.  From the [MDN `FileReader` Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader): _"It cannot be used to read a file by pathname from the user's file system. To read files on the client's file system by pathname, use the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)."_ The File System Access API page seems to be in draft status; not sure if it is implemented anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I came across that as well. I wonder if Electron or native desktop applications have this support already available....

Comment: Yes, this can be easily done using Node's [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and you have access to that module thanks to Electron. You just have to write the logic & UI yourself (asking for permission & storing the permission state & keeping track of the images in that folder...etc)

Comment: Thanks, do you know if a progressive web app might be able to use node's fs module?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to only require permission once to access a file or directory when using the File System Access API. You can do this by storing the file or directory handle in IndexedDB.

https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/#storing-file-handles-or-directory-handles-in-indexeddb